# Не удается создать миграцию базы данных (Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionString'))

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Всем привет, начал изучать ASP.Net Core, для работой с бд собираюсь использовать Entity Framewokr Core. Пытаюсь создать миграцию, но в командной строке PM выводится такая ошибка

`Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionString')`

Подскажите в чем ошибка, как фиксить.

Startup.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using SportsStore.Models;

namespace SportsStore
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration) =>
            Configuration = configuration;

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration["Data.SportsStoreProducts:ConnectionString"]));
            services.AddTransient<IProductRepository, EFProductRepository>();
            services.AddMvc(options => options.EnableEndpointRouting = false);
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseStatusCodePages();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Product}/{action=List}/{id?}");
            });
            SeedData.EnsurePopulated(app);
        }
    }
}
```

Program.cs

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace SportsStore
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                    webBuilder.UseDefaultServiceProvider(options =>
                        options.ValidateScopes = false);
                });
    }
}
```

appsetting.json

```
  "Data": {
    "SportsStoreProducts": {
      "ConnectionString": "Server=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=SportsStore;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true" 
    } 
  }
```

Comment: Опечатка: `ConfigurationString` в коде вместо `ConnectionString`

Comment: поменял, но ошибка осталась

Comment: точка двоеточие